# Using spies in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I was wondering how to use Jasmine Spies to create an outcome of a function in javascript.

I have a `ball.roll` function that uses a randomly generates a score between 1 & 10 & I would like to use this in an another test to ensure that `ball.roll` will equal 3. However I don't quite get how to set up the spy.

I currently have this...

`ball = jasmine.createSpy('ball', ['roll']);`

this creates the .roll method, but I don't quite know how to get it to return 3...

I usually use ruby & rspec so I am used to using doubles and stubs...

any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help:

```
spyOn(ball, 'roll').and.returnValue(3);
```

That way, whenever the function is invoked, the return value is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head it's something like

```
Jasmine.createSpy(ball, roll).andReturnValue(3)
```

Apologies I have limited ability to use this iPad so I can't get the line of code u need but this should give u something to go on

Comment: hey buddy, tried this and the one above. Amongst some other stuff and got a roll method does not exist error... :s

Comment: Try this ... spyOn(ball.roll).and.returnValue(3) ... Really sorry I can't guarantee this code due to iPad issues but it's close, Googling this syntax should get you the right answer